# Python counter for counting the most commmon string listed in the output

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, counter

Hey guys I've been working on this code to do counting the number of string occured in the text document, it's on my previous question and the code appears like this:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Zha\\Desktop\\stringResult\\sguresult_lenght10.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
a = Counter(content.split()).most_common()    
for line in a:
        print line
```

the example of the result of print line will be like this

```
('KERNEL32.dll', 58)
('not', 49)
('.data', 49)
("nRX|'", 20)
('xZGVr', 20)
('TyN*u', 20)
('[Wu^D', 20)
```

the part before comma is the string and the next one is the number of occurrance
Now the question is I need to remove all the brackets outside and the ' ' single quotation in between leaving only the string and number i.e

```
KERNEL32.dll, 58
not, 49
.data, 49
etc
```

I've been trying using regex but it seems the I might got the pattern wrong since the single quotation sometimes is first part of the string itself. Is there any easy way to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for line in a:
    print '%s, %s' % (line[0], line[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` syntax:

```
for line in a:
    print *line
```

The `*` syntax tells the function to treat the elements in a collection as individual parameters.

Example:

```
>>>foo = ('Hello', 'World', 1, 2, 3,)
>>>print foo
('Hello', 'World', 1, 2, 3)
>>>print *foo
'Hello' 'World' 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= dict(Counter(content.split()).most_common())

for i,j in a.items():
    print i,j
```

my answer removes the quotation no need to add new conditions